# How to create surface plot from greyscale image with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, smoothing

Let's say I have a greyscale image (size: 550x150 px). I load the image with matplolib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mp_img
image = mp_img.imread("my-cat.png")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Now, `plt.imshow` displays the image on the screen. But what I want is a surface plot of the greyscale values, something like this:

[image]

.Colour is not really a necessity, but it would be helpful for the height lines. I know, that I need a function of the form `f(x,y) -> z` to create the surface plot. So, I want to use the greyscale value at `(x_pixel,y_pixel)` in my image to get the value of `f`. This leads to my problem:

- I'd like to do some interpolation (e.g. smoothing) of my image values during plotting. This depends also on the size of my meshgrid, so how do I control this? And,
- how do I make a surface plot of the greyscale values from my image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So this is pretty straightforward. Load the data, build the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# generate some sample data
import scipy.misc
lena = scipy.misc.lena()

# downscaling has a "smoothing" effect
lena = scipy.misc.imresize(lena, 0.15, interp='cubic')

# create the x and y coordinate arrays (here we just use pixel indices)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:lena.shape[0], 0:lena.shape[1]]

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, lena ,rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.cm.gray,
        linewidth=0)

# show it
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `150 * 0.15 ~ 22` mesh points it would be nice if I could resolve structures in more detail. I know it is a quite general statement but I'm looking for a smoothing filter which preserves detail despite high contrasts and strongly varying gradients. Anyway, I'll accept your answer if you add a bilateral filter or something similar.

Comment: Accept it or not, as you wish. This is not a coding service, where you get to demand what you want. Show what you have tried and describe where you get stuck.

Comment: What's confusing for me is when I try to move away from examples using the sample data (e.g. `img = scipy.misc.lena()`) to real data (e.g. `img = imread('20141007225851_145162701.png`)) I get __ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1__

There's an obvious difference between the two (the np array is nested one level deeper when it comes from `imread` instead of `misc.data`) but I'm not exactly sure why, but using `img[0]` doesn't work, event though the data format looks the same. I realize it's just something dumb that I'm missing, annoying tho

Comment: I figured it out - you have to make sure that `xx.shape, yy.shape, lena.shape` are all the same; in my case the img I was reading in was actually an rgb file, so I had to add `from skimage.color import rgb2gray;  gray_img = rgb2gray(img)`  and after that `ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, img_sm ...)` worked fine.

Comment: Up 2023 : If you've got this message : `TypeError: gca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'`, `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')` will solve the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cv2

# generate some sample data
import scipy.misc
lena = cv2.imread("./data/lena.png", 0)

# downscaling has a "smoothing" effect
lena = cv2.resize(lena, (100,100))

# create the x and y coordinate arrays (here we just use pixel indices)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:lena.shape[0], 0:lena.shape[1]]

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, lena ,rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
                linewidth=0)

# show it
plt.show()
```

If you want to get color plot, change the code to: "cmap=plt.cm.jet".
So you can get something like this:
[color plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grpth.png)